# Instantiate test contract fails with Contract name is not known

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to adapt the commercial paper tutorial to a custom contract. As soon as I change the contract name, I cannot instantiate it.

In commercial-paper/organization/magnetocorp/contract/lib, I updated paper.js to replace:

```
    static getClass() {
        return 'org.papernet.commercialpaper';
    }
```

... with

```
    static getClass() {
        return 'org.papernet.commercialpapertest';
    }
```

Similarly, in commercial-paper/organization/magnetocorp/contract/lib, I updated papercontract.js to replace:

```
    constructor() {
        // Unique name when multiple contracts per chaincode file
        super('org.papernet.commercialpaper');
    }
```

... with:

```
    constructor() {
        // Unique name when multiple contracts per chaincode file
        super('org.papernet.commercialpapertest');
    }
```

I then changed the instantiate command from:

```
docker exec cliMagnetoCorp peer chaincode instantiate -n papercontract -v 0 -l node -c '{"Args":["org.papernet.commercialpaper:instantiate"]}' -C mychannel -P "AND ('Org1MSP.member')"
```

... to:

```
docker exec cliMagnetoCorp peer chaincode instantiate -n papercontract -v 0 -l node -c '{"Args":["org.papernet.commercialpapertest:instantiate"]}' -C mychannel -P "AND ('Org1MSP.member')"
```

On deleting the couchdb databases, stopping then removing all containers, and rerunning the example from scratch, these changes causes instantiate to fail with `Contract name is not known`:

```
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg transaction returned with failure: Error: Contract name is not known: org.papernet.commercialpapertest
```

Here is the docker log:

```
> papercontract@0.0.3 start /usr/local/src
> fabric-chaincode-node start "--peer.address" "peer0.org1.example.com:7052"
2019-09-08T16:11:08.911Z info [shim:contracts-spi/bootstrap.js]                   
No metadata file supplied in contract, introspection will generate all the data
2019-09-08T16:11:08.914Z info [shim:contracts-spi/chaincodefromcontract.js]       
Using serializers {"transaction":"jsonSerializer","serializers":{}}
2019-09-08T16:11:08.942Z info [shim:lib/chaincode.js]                             
Registering with peer peer0.org1.example.com:7052 as chaincode "papercontract:0"
Command succeeded
2019-09-08T16:11:08.971Z info [shim:lib/handler.js] Successfully registered with peer node. State transferred to "established"
2019-09-08T16:11:08.972Z info [shim:lib/handler.js] Successfully established communication with peer node. State transferred to "ready"
2019-09-08T16:11:08.977Z error [shim:contracts-spi/chaincodefromcontract.js [mychannel-971a76f9] Error: Contract name is not known: org.papernet.commercialpapertest
2019-09-08T16:11:08.977Z error [shim:lib/handler.js] [mychannel-971a76f9] Calling chaincode Init() returned error response [Error: Contract name is not known: org.papernet.commercialpapertest]. Sending ERROR message back to peer
```

Listing installed contracts shows that the contract is installed:

```
Get installed chaincodes on peer:
Name: papercontract, Version: 0, Path: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/contract, Id: a766e52585dbf1c0c9b725a72e66bd0e3f50f83da8641c9a4b4d6aebd6b85777
```

Listing instantiated contracts show that it is not instantiated:

```
Get instantiated chaincodes on channel mychannel:
```

It seems as if the original contract name is set somewhere else also?  If so, I cannot locate it with a "Find in Files" search from VS Code.

Help gratefully received.

Comment: Cleared the Docker cache and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't change the contract name in package.json `papercontract` as the contract installed on peer with details name: `papercontract, Version: 0`